# The subscription does not have QuotaId/Feature required by SKU 'S0' from kind 'QnAMaker'

Tags: .net, azure, botframework, azure-qna-maker, bot-framework-composer

The subscription does not have QuotaId/Feature required by SKU 'S0' from kind 'QnAMaker' .
i am using Bot Framework Composer and i want to add QNA MAKER knowledge base
but it require set up qna maker and i am getting this error now
"The subscription does not have QuotaId/Feature required by SKU 'S0' from kind 'QnAMaker' ."

i am using Bot Framework Composer and i want to add QNA MAKER knowledge base and for this i create resourse in the azure
but it require set up qna maker and i am getting this error now
"The subscription does not have QuotaId/Feature required by SKU 'S0' from kind 'QnAMaker' ."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From now onwards you can't create new QnA Maker. If you have an old QnA Maker in your Azure resources, you use it in Composer.

Answer (score 1):

> The subscription does not have QuotaId/Feature required by SKU 'S0' from kind 'QnAMaker

As per this Jon Gallant blog [article](https://blog.jongallant.com/2021/04/solution-subscription-does-not-have-quotaid-feature-required-by-sku/), it is said that this error occurs because of retirement of S0 SKU's, changing to S will fix the issue.

But there is a [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/accountmanagement/resource-skus/list?tabs=HTTP) that gets the Resource SKU's List for the Azure Cognitive Services that are available in your Azure Subscription:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.CognitiveServices/skus?api-version=2021-10-01
```

[image]

AFAIK, if the specific resource SKU's is not registered/subscribed in our Azure Subscription, then it will throw this exception.